# Missing Feature in check_tcp Nagios Plugin

Tags: linux, bash, nagios

I've got a problem with the `check_tcp` plugin from Nagios and could not find any plugin that works like I need.

I'm sending a string to a port via `check_tcp` and get a number back, in this case 2580. On this number I need to define warning and crital values.

Example:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins# ./check_tcp -H XXXXXXXXXX -p 51031 -E -s "status\r\n" -d 1 -t 30 -e "SOMEThING"
TCP WARNING - Unexpected response from host/socket: 2580|time=0,000358s;;;0,000000;30,000000
```

I need somthing like:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins# ./check_tcp -H XXXXXXXXXX -p 51031 -E -s "status\r\n" -d 1 -t 30 -w  2500 -c 3000
```

Is there anyway to do this or any plugin I've not found yet?

Answer (score 3):

Create your own wrapper, ie. in Perl, to execute the check_tcp internally, then analyse the response and return exit code according to the response.

With so simple check, you might even implement the whole thing in Perl without wrapping the other command.
Sample code is here: http://xmodulo.com/how-to-write-simple-tcp-server-and-client-in-perl.html

Comment: Or just use Perl to connect to a TCP socket.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i wrote a small bash script that basicly works fine... Just still got some bugs inside, so if there are any ideas for improvement:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Check TCP Response fuer NAGIOS
#
# by Kjell Krenz
#
#
# Version 0.1
#
#


while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        -h)
            HOST=$2
            shift 2
        ;;
        -p)
            PORT=$2
            shift 2
        ;;
        -s)
            STRING=$2
            shift 2
        ;;
        -w)
            WARN=$2
            shift 2
        ;;
        -c)
            CRIT=$2
            shift 2
        ;;
        -m)
            MSG=$2
            shift 2
        ;;
        *)
            echo "Usage:"
            echo "-h: Host (IP)"
            echo "-p: TCP Port"
            echo "-s: STRING"
            echo "-w: WARNING VALUE"
            echo "-c: CRITICAL VALUE"
            echo "-m: Custom Message Label"
            shift 1
        ;;
    esac
done



exec 3<>/dev/tcp/$HOST/$PORT
echo -en "$STRING\n" >&3
RESPONSE="`cat <&3`"



if [ $RESPONSE -lt $WARN ]
then
    echo "OK- $RESPONSE $MSG"
    exit 0
elif [ $RESPONSE -ge $CRIT ]
then
    echo "CRITICAL- $RESPONSE $MSG"
    exit 2
elif [ $RESPONSE -ge $WARN ]
then
    echo "WARNING- $RESPONSE $MSG"
    exit 1
else
echo "UNKNOWN- $RESPONSE"
exit 3
fi

esac
echo $RESPONSE
exit $EXIT
```